# How to fetch record from two different collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lookup

I'm trying to fetch record from two different collections but when I'm getting result from one collection and matching array is getting empty.

```
var data = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id:{type:String},
    coin_key:{type:String},
    address:{type:String},
    label:{type:String}
});

var coin_info = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    wallet_name:{type:String},
});

var deposte_model = mongoose.model('deposit',data);

var get_coin_info = mongoose.model('coin_infos',coin_info);

deposte_model.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'get_coin_info',
            localField: 'coin_key',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'orderdetails'
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res);
});
```

result looks like this:

```
[{ 
    _id: 5a448ca723df911015711d8c,
    user_id: '5a3e432e42850631fceeda8e',
    coin_key: '5a43634fabe09f65ddf75c0c',
    label: 'test',
    address: '1QLVovgdv8PrnSXfLD2J5YS2eKVKekGkTK',
    __v: 0,
    orderdetails: [] 
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

$lookup from should be collection name in MongoDB. In your case 'coin_info' not 'get_coin_info'. Does that help?

Also if you are willing to make this even better I would suggest you learn about MongoDB populating. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: i as you said i have did ,but not getting output.

Comment: `mongoose.model('coin_infos',coin_info);` should also be `mongoose.model('coin_info',coin_info);`

Comment: i am trying with terminal but also getting empty array.

Comment: db.deposits.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: 'coin_infos', localField: 'coin_key', foreignField: '_id', as: 'user' } }]).pretty();
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a4b0f4a32c51230087a5453"),
 "user_id" : "5a4b0787a0050c20a6be44b2",
 "coin_key" : "5a4b07b2a0050c20a6be44b3",
 "label" : "Test",
 "address" : "17dhdZSEtoabadme6M9WBnqS4n6WU3ycJm",
 "__v" : 0,
 "user" : [ ]
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a4b0f7ce170a030ca189fdd"),
 "user_id" : "5a4b0787a0050c20a6be44b2",
 "coin_key" : "5a4b07b2a0050c20a6be44b3",
 "label" : "Test2",
 "address" : "1KUtoFZ5tcpzENvkorS4XxtQ8h",
 "__v" : 0,
 "user" : [ ]
}